# Returning Mapkit Userlocation Coordinates

Tags: iphone, mapkit

whenever I try to return the lat/long coordinates for my current location, my application crashes with no explanation of the error...

```
NSLog(@"%@", mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate);
```

I am waiting until the phone finds the location as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate` is a struct while the `%@` format specifier expects an object. This will work:

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,
                 mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this didn't work for me. It's taking me to the coordinates (0.0000, 0.0000). Below is my code if you have a chance to check it out. Thanks for the help!

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord = {mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:myCoord animated:YES];

    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

    [mapView setDelegate:self];
```