# Retrieve UserLocation Coordinate with MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I"m using MapKit in my application and disaply the user location with

```
[mapview setShowUserLocation:YES];
```

I want to set the region.center.latitude and region.center.longitude with the coordinate of the userLocation, how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my answer, I try something like that and its working:

```
//inside my ViewDidLOad
locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locManager setDelegate:self];
[locManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation  {

   CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
   [maptView setCenterCoordiante:loc];  

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Much easier:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 1500, 1500);
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the mapView.delegate!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, this didn't work for me. It's taking me to the coordinates (0.0000, 0.0000). Below is my code if you have a chance to check it out. Thanks for the help!

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };

CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord = {mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:myCoord animated:YES];

region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

[mapView setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your question : 
[Returning Mapkit Userlocation Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652289/returning-mapkit-userlocation-coordinates/1652306#1652306)

(uses the `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude` and `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude properties` )

and then inject those coordinates into the

`-(void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated`

of your MKMapView instance.

Comment: yeah or I can use the region.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude; I think it will work right?

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure if it works, I would recommend you to create a local CLLocationCoordinate2D and inject it in the given selector. You get control over the animation parameter that could also make your app look nicer with an animation.

Comment: I don't really know how to use the selector you gave me but I will try, if you have any link to show me will be good too. thanks

Comment: something like this should be ok : 
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord = {mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:myCoord animated:YES];

Comment: I still have a little problem, when I do NSLog(@"%i": mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude); I don't have a location number, I have something like thaT : 71502240

Answer (score 0):

Using delegate:

1. Add Mapkit delegate: MKMapViewDelegate
2. Achieve method:MapView didUpdateUserLocation

   > ```
   > -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
   >     MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate,
   >         500, 500);
   >     [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
   > }
   > ```

Without delegate:

```
[self.mapView setuserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];
```